# How to implement css-pure cross-browser parallax effect using transforms?

Tags: html, css, background, transform, parallax

I'm trying to implement css-pure parallax effect using transforms on a website I'm developing ([redd](https://www.redd.co.mz)). Nearly all pages of the website have parallax sections on header and footer. A parallax effect would surely make the website a little bit more eye-catching and interactive.

My html:

```php
<!-- Some code before -->
    <section class="parallax">
        <div class="parallax-bg footer"
          data-src="../../assets/img/home/content/beautiful-black-woman-working-thinking-smart.webp">
          <div class="parallax-overlay">
            <div class="parallax-content">
              <h2>DESCUBRA MAIS O QUE AS NOSSAS <br> SOLUÇÕES-CHAVE PODEM FAZER <br> NO SEU NEGÓCIO</h2>
            </div>
            <span class="cta-btn">
              <a href="<?php echo $pages['SERVICE'] ?>">SERVIÇOS REDD</a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<!-- Some code after -->
```

My css:

```css
/* Styles rules before */

.parallax {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
    /* set a fixed height for the section */
}

.parallax-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.parallax-bg {
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
    will-change: transform;
}

.parallax-bg.footer {
    background-image: var(--background-image);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.parallax-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 50vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Styles rules after */
```

I know about `background-attachment: fixed` property, but it has so many issues that in the end I dumped it. It has issues regarding performance (noticeable especially on mobile devices or even on any device using Chrome browser or any browser based on Chrome). Also, it seems `background-attachment: fixed` doesn't work in ios safari.

I applied some transforms properties to elements of parallax section, but it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm missing, or if I implemented the transforms well or If my html structure isn't good but please, help!